# >> << and -> Syntax in arduino

Tags: programming, c++

I was trying to follow [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SPIEEPROM) tutorial and came across `>>`. What exactly does this do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>` is right shift a value by a certain number of bits.
`<<` is left shift a value by a certain number of bits.
`->` is accessing a member of a class or struct that is referenced by a pointer.

## Right Shift and Left Shift

If you have a binary number `0b00010000` and right shift it two bits you get `0b00000100`. The C notation for that is `val >> 2`.  The same for left shift - `val << 2` would result in `0b01000000`.

## Pointers and members

Normally when you access a member of a class or struct you use `.`, such as `Serial.println()`.  However it is possible to make a *pointer* to a class instance, and when you do you need to access the members with `->` instead of `.` - such as `mySerial->println()`.
This arrow notation serves as syntactic sugar: `mySerial->println()` is interpreted as `(*mySerial).println()`. The parentheses are necessary because the dereferencing operator `*` has a lower order of precedence compared to the dot `.` operator.